# Flutter Firebase - How to Add User uid to Document

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I want to add user uid to any document added.

I managed to get uid with the following code:

```
Future getCurrentUser() async {
  final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
  final uid = user.uid;
  print(uid);
  return uid.toString();
}
```

and I want to add it here :

```
void addData(){
  databaseReference.collection(("ads"))
    .add({
      'category': '$category',
      'location': '$location',
      'subject': '$adName',
      'userId': '$userid',
  });
}
```

and when I try to define the variable userid in class I get the following error:

> error: Expected a class member. (expected_class_member at [hpxksa]

> lib/Screens/add_ad.dart:59)
> error: Only static members can be accessed in initializers.

and if I declare it inside the widget it is recorded in database like this:

[image]

Comment: how are u defining it in class

Comment: userid = getCurrentUser();

Comment: Since getCurrentUser is async, you'll need to await it to get the value out of the Future it returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getCurrentUser()` is asynchronous, therefore it returns a instance of `Future`, you have to do the following:

```
void addData()async{
  String userid = await getCurrentUser();
  databaseReference.collection("ads").add({
      'category': '$category',
      'location': '$location',
      'subject': '$adName',
      'userId': '$userid',
  });
}
```

Comment: it is the same name only the pic changed :)